# FORM don't submit anything

Tags: php, html

I have some php and html code, what I want to do is just catch the data from form and print it in one file. But when I click submit there is no data.

I've tried to break the code to be 2 part but there is no change.

This is the code:

```html
<section id="register" class="section-with-bg wow fadeInUp">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="section-header">
              <h2>Register</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="form">
                <div id="errormessage"></div>
                <form id="data" action="#" method="post" class="contactForm">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="name1" class="form-control" id="name1" placeholder="Nama Depan" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pekerjaan" id="pekerjaan" placeholder="Pekerjaan" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="nip" class="form-control" id="nip" placeholder="NIP (Jika Anda Seorang ASN)"/>
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="pwd" placeholder="Password" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd2" id="pwd2" placeholder="Repeat Password" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="tlp" class="form-control" id="tlp" placeholder="Telepon" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" name="hp" class="form-control" id="hp" placeholder="HP" />
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Alamat"></textarea>
                            <!--<div class="validation"></div>-->
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center"><input type="submit" value="Submit" name ="submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <?php
      $nama =isset($_POST['name1']);
      $pekerjaan =isset($_POST['pekerjaan']);
      $nip =isset($_POST['nip']);
      $email =isset($_POST['email']);
      $pwd =isset($_POST['pwd']);
      $pwd2 =isset($_POST['pwd2']);
      $tlp =isset($_POST['tlp']);
      $hp =isset($_POST['hp']);
      $message =isset($_POST['message']);

      echo $nama;
      echo $pekerjaan;
      echo $nip;
      echo $email;
      echo $pwd;
      echo $pwd2;
      echo $tlp;
      echo $message;
    ?>
```

I try to make simple code with just 1 input and 1 submit button and it works

Update:
Thank you guys for your help I already solved the problem I got some error in my JS code and now my code working :)

Comment: Read over [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) : Returns TRUE if var exists and has any value other than NULL. FALSE otherwise.

Comment: Just needs to add an if statement.

Comment: I have tried if statement it cause error to my code I assume submit button is work but when I repair the code and run the code again still nothing print it

Comment: Check the answers below and try it out.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me I really appreciate it. I have tried all you guys suggest to me. But I still have no clue why my code is not working. Maybe I should rewrite my code and analyze why the code is not working properli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code returns "boolean" values because you assign boolean values to your variables:

`$message =isset($_POST['message']);` this line will assign true or false to the `$message` variable.

If you want to check if the value is isset so you can print it then you have to do it like:

```
$message = isset($_POST['message'])? $message = $_POST['message']: $message = '';
```

This is just an example in 1 of your lines. The same logic applies to all your variables.

Comment: thats answer why the code always print '1', but I have delete isset() in my code and nothing print it

Comment: Are you sure you delete it right? I mean testing your code locally works fine.

Also to avoid caching issue remove the action from the form like:

`<form id="data" method="post" class="contactForm">` It should work properly without keeping memory of your old inputted data.

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $nama =isset($_POST['name1']);
      $pekerjaan =isset($_POST['pekerjaan']);
      $nip =isset($_POST['nip']);
      $email =isset($_POST['email']);
      $pwd =isset($_POST['pwd']);
      $pwd2 =isset($_POST['pwd2']);
      $tlp =isset($_POST['tlp']);
      $hp =isset($_POST['hp']);
      $message =isset($_POST['message']);

      echo $nama;
      echo $pekerjaan;
      echo $nip;
      echo $email;
      echo $pwd;
      echo $pwd2;
      echo $tlp;
      echo $message;
}
    ?>
```

Replace this with your current php code. You are not checking weather the form is submitted or not. It can be done using an if statement where it checks if the submit button was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

try adding this on top of your code

```
<?php
  session_start();
  extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);
  extract($_GET, EXTR_SKIP);
  extract($_SESSION, EXTR_SKIP);
  extract($_FILES, EXTR_SKIP);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there still no change

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is in the way you assigned your variable values: `$nama =isset($_POST['name1']);`. Simplify it as `$nama = $_POST['name1'];`. Keep in mind that if your site visitor doesn't change (any of the) input fields, those inputs may show up with your `placeholder=` values.

```
<?php
  $nama = $_POST['name1'];
  $pekerjaan = $_POST['pekerjaan'];
  $nip = $_POST['nip'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];
  $pwd2 = $_POST['pwd2'];
  $tlp = $_POST['tlp'];
  $hp = $_POST['hp'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];

  echo $nama;
  echo $pekerjaan;
  echo $nip;
  echo $email;
  echo $pwd;
  echo $pwd2;
  echo $tlp;
  echo $message;
?>
```